# Sharp Exponential Inequality of $\frac{e^{-a\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

I am trying to find a sharp inequality of $\frac{e^{-a\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}$ s.t. we can write: $$\frac{e^{-a\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+n^2}} \leq \frac{e^{-ax}}{x}f(an) .$$ Here, $a,x>0, n \in \mathbb{N}. $ Any particular technique to answer these kinds of questions will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @DevanshBhardwaj After dividing both sides by $e^{-ax}/x$, as $x\to \infty$, we get $1 \le f(an)$, right?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes sorry. I made the mistake of taking it as product of $e^{\frac{-an^2}{2}}$ and $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Answer (score 3):

The RHS approaches infinity as x approaches 0. Also, if $f(an)$ has the value 1, then the RHS is always greater than LHS. The derivative of $\frac{e^{−ax}}{x}$ is negative for all $a,x>0$, and that of the LHS is also negative.

Dividing the LHS by $\frac{e^{−ax}}{x}$ and taking the limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$ would give $f(an)$. We get
\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{n^2}{x^2}}}\exp{(ax(1-\sqrt{1+\frac{n^2}{x^2}}))}\le f(an)\end{align}
Binomial expansion of the square roots and dismissal of terms of order higher than $\frac{n^2}{x^2}$:
\begin{align}\frac{e^{-\frac{an^2}{2x}}}{1+\frac{n^2}{2x^2}}\le f(an)\end{align}

Thus, \begin{align}1\le f(an)\end{align}
**EDIT**

A suggestion in the comments states an easy way to do this
\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{n^2}{x^2}}}\exp{(-\frac{an^2}{\sqrt{n^2+x^2}+x})}\le f(an)\end{align}
which, upon taking the limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$, gives the same result.

Comment: One simple way is to rewrite it as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{n^2}{x^2}}}\mathrm{exp}\left({-\frac{an^2}{\sqrt{n^2 + x^2} + x}}\right) \le f(an).$$

Comment: A basic trick: 
$$- a (\sqrt{x^2 + n^2} - x)
= - a\frac{(x^2 + n^2)  - x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + n^2} + x}
= - \frac{an^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + n^2} + x}$$

Comment: ok that is good. Ill make the change

Comment: Your approach is also good. I just give another approach.

Comment: Actually, directly taking $x\to \infty$ for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{n^2}{x^2}}}\mathrm{exp}\left({-\frac{an^2}{\sqrt{n^2 + x^2} + x}}\right) \le f(an)$ gives $1 \le f(an)$, :).

Comment: Yes it does. It can even be seen that as $x\rightarrow \infty$, $\sqrt{x^2+n^2}\rightarrow x$. I just cannot figure out how much to simplify the solution